# Invisible RelativeLayout with a SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to develop a face recognition application and I am using a SurfaceView inside a RelativeLayout. I was able to make the SurfaceView "TRANSPARENT" so I did not need to see the Camera preview, but now I am having a white background caused by the RelativeLayout and I can't make it Invisible so I don't see this background in my application.

I tried many things and i looked a lot of posts here in SO but I didn't find a solution for my situation.

Xml code (margins in relativelayout and surfaceview were for testing purposes):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:visibility="invisible">

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_preview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: If you want the `SurfaceView` to be invisible, why is it the parent `RelativeLayout` is the one with `android:visibility="invisible"` instead? That would effectively make all its children invisible as well

Comment: hey @Cruceo, I want both the RelativeLayout and the SurfaceView invisible, I used "setZOrderOnTop(true)" in the surfaceview so I don't see the preview but the RelativeLayout is still there although it has the visibility="invisible"

Answer (score 0):

instead of making it invisible remove it altogether by adding this to the layout:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

and then set it to visible programmatically when you need it again.

Comment: Hi, if i put the visibility = gone in the Layout I still see the white background of the RelativeLayout but I can't access the data provided by the SurfaceView.